# Using a url to apply an if statement

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a site that has a paragraph text that is the same on every page. But I need to change it for one specific page. I've set the JS to change the text in the paragraph to this...

```
    // set up variable to get url
    var getUrl = window.location.href;
    //split the url 
    var getPrefixBySlash = getUrl.split('/');

    // call the variable
    getUrl;

    if(getPrefixBySlash[4] === "group?course=111#" || "group?course=111") {
         console.log("it is equal");
    } else { 
         console.log("it is not equal"); 
    };
```

This is returning as "it is equal" when I am on a page that ends with `group?course-101`

Is there something wrong with the comparrison?

Note: the or statement is there because sometimes the url has that # at the end and sometimes it doesn't.

Any help would be good. thanks.

Comment: What do you mean by `call the variable`? That line isn't doing anything.

Comment: that returns the location of the url...try it in your browser you should get the url to this page.

Comment: That `if` is - probably - not doing what you want it to. The first check assesses whether the variable is equal to the posted string, but then it's going to return `true` regardless, since you've declared a non-empty String. Further to what @dustytrash is trying to say: you've already initialised the variable, you don't have to 'call' it to have it assign its value.

Comment: `getPrefixBySlash[4] === "group?course=111#" || "group?course=111"` should be `getPrefixBySlash[4] === "group?course=111#" || getPrefixBySlash[4] === 
 "group?course=111"` - each part around `||` (and `&&`) is taken as its own 'if' clause, they don't combine as `left == right1 || right2` it's `left == right1 ... OR ... left == right2`

Comment: "_that returns the location of the url_" In the console, and technically also in the script, but you're not using the returned value anywhere.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This line isn't actually doing anything.

```
// call the variable
getUrl;
```

If you meant to print the variable, use `console.log(getURl);`

This if statement is wrong.

```
if(getPrefixBySlash[4] === "group?course=111#" || "group?course=111") {
```

You need to put the whole statement after the `||`.

e.g `if(getPrefixBySlash[4] === "group?course=111#" || getPrefixBySlash[4] === "group?course=111")` (note the added 'getPrefixBySlash ===)

**Solution:**
**You can instead check if the URL contains the string that you want, using variable.contains("someString").**

**Example**:

```
// set up variable to get url
var getUrl = window.location.href;
//split the url 
var getPrefixBySlash = getUrl.split('/');

// print the variable
console.log(getUrl);

if(getPrefixBySlash[4].contains("group?course=111") 
{
     console.log("it is equal");
} 
else 
{ 
     console.log("it is not equal"); 
};
```

Comment: Thank you. I actually tried everyone elses suggestions but they weren't working. I did have some other objects causing problems with the outcome so that was another issue. Thanks again I ended up using this as it was less code too.

Answer (score 3):

you are missing a comparison:

```
 if(
  getPrefixBySlash[4] === "group?course=111#" || 
  getPrefixBySlash[4] === "group?course=111"
 ) {
```

If you omit the `===` it will use the string as a boolean, and a non empty string is truthy therefore it always enters the true branch.

PS: you can't call a variable.

Comment: Thanks Jonas, I think this will work for me. Not sure why everyone answers but then gives me a negative rep...-_- It's a legitimate question. Still not getting it to work but this helps. I think theres some other JS interfering...

Answer (score 0):

You could not use `getPrefixBySlash[4] === "group?course=111#" || "group?course=111"`.

But you can try to let your multiple strings in string array then use `includes` function.

```
if(["group?course=111#","group?course=111"].includes(getPrefixBySlash[4])){

}
```